# Show that the positive existential theory is undecidable

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, formal-languages, decidability

To show that the positive existential theory of $\mathbb{C}[t, e^{\lambda t} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$ in the language $\{+, \cdot , ' , 0 , 1, t\}$ is undecidable we have to prove the following: $$n \in \mathbb{N} \leftrightarrow \exists x \left (n \in \mathbb{C} \land tx'=nx \land x(1)=1\right )$$

So do we have to do the following?

We suppose that the positive existential theory of $\mathbb{C}[t, e^{\lambda t} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$ in the language $\{+, \cdot , ' , 0, 1, t\}$ is decidable, i.e., there is an algorithm that answers to positive existential questions over  $(\mathbb{C}[t, e^{\lambda t} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}];+, \cdot , ' , 0, 1, t)$.

We want to reduce the positive existential theory $\mathbb{N}$ in the language $\{+, \cdot , 0, 1\}$ into the positive existential theory of $\mathbb{C}[t, e^{\lambda t} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$ in the language $\{+, \cdot , ' , 0, 1, t\}$.

Is this correct?

But which is the mapping of the reduction?

Comment: Interesting question. Your notation $x(1)=1$ suggests that you allow to evaluate the polynomial expressions in your ring, but this is not actually mentioned in the language. Could you clarify whether this is allowed or not?

Comment: No, this cannot be expressed by the language. We have to write it in a way that is allowed in the language. @JoelDavidHamkins

Comment: I found now in my notes that we can express "$x(1)=1$" as "$z-1 \mid x-1$". Why does this stand? @JoelDavidHamkins Do you have an idea about the reduction? Or do we not do it as I said in my question above?

Comment: I think you mean $t-1$ rather than $z-1$.  You are saying that polynomial/exponential expression $x(t)$ has $x(1)=1$ just in case it is a multiple of the term $(t-1)$.

Comment: But that doesn't seem true to me. For example, take $x=\frac 1ee^t$, which has $x(1)=1$. But unless I am mistaken, I don't think we have that $t-1$ divides $x-1$. (It would be true in the polynomial ring, but not in this exponential-polynomial ring.)

Comment: I don't really understand the close votes, since I think the question is interesting. Can you define $\mathbb{Z}$ in the structure $\mathbb{C}[t,e^{\lambda t}]_{\lambda\in \mathbb{C}}$ by an existential formula in the language of rings with differentiation and a constant for the polynomial $t$?

Comment: Yes, I meant $t-1$. Why does it stand in the polynomial ring but not in the exponential-polynomial ring? $$$$ To define $\mathbb{Z}$ in the structure $\mathbb{C}[t,e^{\lambda t}]_{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}}$ by an existential formula in the language of rings with differentiation and a constant for polynomial $t$, we want to express $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ in the structure $\mathbb{C}[t,e^{\lambda t}]$, right? @JoelDavidHamkins

Comment: First of all $n$ has to be a constant in $\mathbb{C}[t,e^{\lambda t}]$, so $n\in \mathbb{C}$. If we want that the solution $tx'=nx$ is a polynomial we want that $n\in \mathbb{N}$, right? To  get $\mathbb{Z}$ do we have to take an other differential equation? For example $tx'=-nx$? Or do we get it somehow else? @JoelDavidHamkins

Comment: Or do you mean something else? @JoelDavidHamkins

Comment: I posted an answer. The issue of $x(1)=1$ seems unnecessary to me now.

Comment: To address any lingering concerns about the suitability of the question for MO, I'd recommend an editing of the question to give some context and/or motivation for the research interest, and maybe a light editing to increase clarity (we are dealing with the positive existential theory of $\mathbb{C}[t, e^{\lambda t}]_{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}}$ as a model of the theory of rings with a derivation operator; it sometimes helps to use English words instead of symbols). Other than that, I agree with Joel David Hamkins that this question is suitable for MO.

Comment: The issue of $x(1)=1$ returned, in order to make the assertion positive. See the comments on my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I like this question very much. Before answering, let me try to
explain the question in my words.

You are considering the structure $\mathbb{C}[t,e^{\lambda t}]_{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}}$,
which is the ring of all polynomial expressions over $\mathbb{C}$ in the
indeterminate variable $t$ and $e^{\lambda t}$, for any $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$.
So this ring has objects like this: $$t\qquad\qquad (t^2+5)e^{3t}+te^{\pi
t}\qquad\qquad t^2e^{\pi i t}+5t^{10}.$$ We consider this structure in the
language of rings, using addition, multiplication, 0, 1, augmented
with the differentiation operation $f'$ and a constant symbol for
the polynomial $t$. So we may freely make terms like $t^2x''+tx$
and so on, where $x$ is a variable ranging over the ring. The
exponential polynomials are simply points in the structure. The question is whether the positive existential theory of this structure is undecidable.

In order to show that the existential theory of this structure is
undecidable, it suffices to show that we may define the natural
numbers in it by an existential property, for then we would be
able to reduce any existential question in the language of
arithmetic, that is, in the structure
$\langle\mathbb{N},+,\cdot,0,1\rangle$, to an existential question
in your structure. Since the existential theory of arithmetic is
undecidable, it will follow that the existential theory of your
structure will be undecidable.

Notice that we can define the constant polynomials, that is, the
elements of $\mathbb{C}$ in your ring, since these are precisely
the $x$ that satisfy $x'=0$.

Let us view $\mathbb{N}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$, which is a
subset of your ring $\mathbb{C}[t,e^{\lambda t}]_{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}}$. Using the idea
you suggested, we can define $\mathbb{N}$ in your ring by an
existential formula as follows:

**Lemma.** $n\in\mathbb{N}$ if and only if
$\mathbb{C}[t,e^{\lambda t}]_{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}}\models n'=0\wedge \exists x\
tx'=nx\wedge x\neq 0$.

**Proof.** If $n$ is a natural number, then it is constant and so
the derivative $n'$ is $0$. But furthermore, if $x=t^n$, then
$x'=nt^{n-1}$, and so $tx'=nx$. So $n$ satisfies the definition.

Conversely, suppose that $n\in\mathbb{C}$ and there is some nonzero $x$ in
your ring with $tx'=nx$. I claim that the only solutions of this
differential equation are of the form $\lambda t^n$, for
$\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$. Certainly any expression of this form is a
solution. And if $x$ and $y$ are both solutions of the
differential equation, then $(\frac
xy)'=\frac{x'y-y'x}{y^2}=\frac{\frac{nx}ty-\frac{ny}tx}{y^2}=0$.
So every solution is a constant multiple of $t^n$. Since this
occurs only for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ in your ring, it follows that $n$
is a natural number. **QED**

So we have defined $\mathbb{N}$ by an existential formula in your
structure, and therefore the existential theory of your structure
is undecidable. Any existential assertion in arithmetic, such as
the halting problem, can be transformed to an existential theory
in your structure.

The existential assertion in the lemma is not positive, however, because of the $x\neq 0$ part. But we can replace $x\neq 0$ there with the assertion that $(t-1)$ divides $x-1$, since once we know that $x$ is a solution of $tx'=nx$, we know that $x$ must have the form $x=\lambda t^n$, and the only way that $t-1$ can divide $\lambda t^n-1$ is if $\lambda=1$. Thus, we have:

$$n\in\mathbb{N}\iff \mathbb{C}[t,e^{\lambda t}]_{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}}\models n'=0\wedge \exists x\
tx'=nx\wedge \exists y\ (t-1)y=x-1.$$

So the natural numbers are defined by a positive existential assertion in your exponential polynomial ring.

Therefore, for any positive existential assertion $\exists n_0,n_1,\ldots,n_k\ \varphi(\vec n)$ in the language of arithmetic, where $\varphi$ is quantifier free, we may translate this to $\exists n_0,\ldots,n_k( n_0\in\mathbb{N}\wedge\cdots\wedge n_k\in\mathbb{N}\wedge\varphi(\vec n)$ in the language of your ring, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is an abbreviation for the formula displayed above.  The original assertion will be true in arithmetic just in case the translation is true in your exponential polynomial ring.

Comment: I realized that one must add $x\neq 0$ to the definition in the lemma in order to avoid unwanted solutions, but now this is not "positive". So we get undecidability of the existential theory, but not (yet) for the positive existential theory. Perhaps one can get rid of this irritation somehow.

Comment: The original condition $x(1)=1$ would eliminate the unwanted solution.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. But I don't see how to express that in the language at hand. We can't seem to evaluate the exponential/polynomial expressions at a given complex number, using only the allowed language.

Comment: Why not (as suggested in a comment) $(t-1) | (x-1)$?  It is true for $\lambda t^n$ only when $\lambda=1$.  More formally, $\exists y \; (x-1)=y\cdot(t-1)$.

Comment: Ah, yes, this works with polynomials, and so it is fine here. My earlier objection was that this does not define $x(1)=1$ in the full ring, since $x=\frac 1ee^t$ is a counterexample, but it is fine once you know that $x$ is a polynomial. I'll edit.

Comment: I understand it now!! Thank you so much!! :-) $$$$ 
When we had the ring $\mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda t}]_{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}}$ where we have no polynomials,would we again want to express $\mathbb{N}$ in the structure by a positive existential formula? If so, would we then take instead of the differential equation $tx′=nx$ the differential equation $x′=nx$, which has the solution $e^{nt}$? Or would we do something else? @JoelDavidHamkins

Comment: It was a nice problem. I don't know how to do it without the polynomials. The property $\exists x\ x'=nx$ won't work, because this is true of any complex number $n$, since $(e^{\lambda t})'=\lambda e^{\lambda t}$.  So your suggested property does not define the natural numbers.

Comment: Ok... And when we have the ring $\mathbb{C}[t]$ do we do exactly the same as above? @JoelDavidHamkins

Comment: Yes, in the polynomial ring, we can define $\mathbb{N}$ just as in my answer.

Comment: When we want to prove that the positive existential theory of $\mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda t}]_{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}}$ is undecidable, do we maybe have to use the language $\{+, \cdot , ' , 0, 1, e^t \}$ or $\{+, \cdot , ' , 0, 1\}$ instead of $\{+, \cdot , ' , 0, 1, t\}$ ? In this ring we don't need the variable $t$, do we? @JoelDavidHamkins