# Is the positive existential theory undecidable?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, computability-theory, formal-languages, decidability

Could you tell if the positive existential theory of $\mathbb{C}[e^{\mu x} \mid \mu \in \mathbb{C}]$ is undecidable in the language $\{+, \cdot , \frac{d}{dx} , 0, 1, e^x\}$ ?

How can we prove the (un)decidability?

Comment: See the OP's related question at http://mathoverflow.net/q/224046/1946

Comment: The way you ask the question suggests that you somehow know already that it is undecidable (since you ask how we could prove this, rather than whether it is true).  But is that right--are you claiming to know already that it is undecidable? If not, I'd suggest editing the question to use a different wording.

Comment: I am not really sure that it is undecidable... I edited my question... Is it now better? @JoelDavidHamkins

Comment: Do you want the language to include an "evaluation" operation?

Comment: What do you mean? @NoahSchweber

Comment: He means: "is there an operation $ev$ which allows us to set the value of $x$" so that for example we can do $ev(e^x, 4)$ which then equals $e^4$?

Comment: Such an operation isn't in the language... Is this operator necessary? @AndrejBauer

Comment: I do not know why you are asking me whether it is necessary. We are just asking a technical question: "Did you by any chance mean to include evaluation in the language?"

Comment: If you have an evaluation function, then you can define the integers, and so it will be undecidable.

Comment: Ahaa... Ok... Can we not define the evaluation function in an existential way, as we defined in the post http://mathoverflow.net/questions/224046/show-that-the-positive-existential-theory-is-undecidable the $x(1)=1$ ? How exactly can we define then the integers? @JoelDavidHamkins

Comment: Can you decide whether $\exists u \exists v \ u^2 = v^3 + 1 + e^x + e^{2x} + e^{3x} + e^{4x} + e^{5x}$?  (With shorter versions of the right hand side, the answer is yes, but even that is not trivial.)  The challenge for decidability is bounding the number of summands in $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Matt, the answer to any single inquiry is either "yes" or "no". To prove undecidability, you need to embed an entire undecidable decision problem, not a single difficult question whose particular answer we don't yet know.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, I agree, but I think it's more likely in the decidable but difficult category.

Comment: @MaryStar With an evaluation function, we can define the integers using the fact that $e^{2\pi ki}=1$ exactly when $k$ is an integer. So $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $\exists \lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ (i.e. $\lambda'=0$) with $e^\lambda=1$ and $e^{\lambda k}=1$.

Comment: I see... So it is $$k \in \mathbb{Z} \leftrightarrow \exists \lambda \left (\lambda '=0 \land k '=0 \land e^{\lambda}=1 \land e^{\lambda k}=1\right )$$ right? Or do we not need the condition $k'=0$ ? $$$$ To do this do we maybe have to replace the element $e^x$ in the language by the predicate $x \mapsto e^x$ ? @JoelDavidHamkins

Comment: @MaryStar You may not need $k'=0$ but you do need $\lambda\neq0$, which you can formulate as $\exists\mu(\lambda\mu=1)$.

Comment: @MaryStar Without the evaluation function, the structure becomes "purely algebraic": you can rename the language as $(+,\cdot,D,0,1,X)$ where $X$ is a constant and $D$ is a unary function. The structure makes sense over any field $k$: take the group $k$-algebra $k[(k,+)]$, with basis denoted by $(X^\lambda)_{\lambda\in k}$, where $X$ is interpreted as $X^1$ and $D$ acts as by $X^\lambda\mapsto\lambda X^\lambda$.

Comment: Ok... So with the conditions $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$, $e^{\lambda}=1$ and $e^{\lambda k}=1$ it follows that $k$ is always an integer, right? $$$$ Could you explain further to me your last comment, about the language? I haven't really understood it... @LaurentMoret-Bailly

Comment: So, do we have to use the language $\{+, \cdot , ' , 0 , 1, e^{t} , T(t)\}$ where $T(t): t \mapsto e^t$ ? Or is there an other way to express the condition $e^{\lambda }=1$ ? @JoelDavidHamkins

Comment: @MaryStar I was only observing that without an evaluation function, it becomes irrelevant to think of $e^t$ as a function of $t$, and in fact "$t$" makes no sense, so it is better to rename $e^t$ and $d/dt$ with abstract symbols such as $X$ and $D$. For instance, I think there is no way to define the complex number $e$ by a formula of your language.

Comment: So, do we have to use the language $\{+, \cdot , D, 0, 1, X, T\}$ where $X=e$, $D: X^{\lambda} \mapsto \lambda X^{\lambda}$ and $T: \lambda \mapsto X^{\lambda}$?  @LaurentMoret-Bailly

Comment: @MaryStar: I am not sure what you mean by "have to". What you have to do is state your problem(s) in precise terms. The point of my (and other people's) comments is that you get different problems by including (or not) some sort of evaluation function in your language. All these problems may be interesting.

Comment: At the beginning I wanted to prove this structure: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/224046/show-that-the-positive-existential-theory-is-undecidable Then I wanted to prove it when we have just the exponential ring, not exponential-polynomial... But we cannot use the language $\{+, \cdot , ', 0, 1, t\}$ because of $t$, right? So, by what do we have to replace $t$ ? @LaurentMoret-Bailly

Comment: Does it stand that $e^x -1 \mid e^{kx} -1$ if and only if $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ ? @JoelDavidHamkins

Comment: Perhaps it is a language issue, but several of your comments here on on your other question mention what we "must" do or what we "have to" do or what we "cannot" do. But that way of saying things carries mathematical meaning that I don't think you intend. For example, nobody is claiming that you must use a certain language in order to have undecidability, since obviously there could be other languages, including trivial modifications, which could still give undecidability. I think you'll get a better reception for your questions and comments if you take care to ask exactly what you intend.

Comment: Ok, I will take into consideration... @JoelDavidHamkins

Comment: I thought the following:If the statement that I wrote in my previous comment is true, we could show that undecidability of the ring in the language $\{+, \cdot , ', 0, 1\}$ as follows:$$k\in \mathbb{Z} \Leftrightarrow e^x-1\mid e^{kx}-1$$ 
We know that $e^x$ is the solution of the differetial equation $y_1'=y_1$ and $e^{kx}$ is the solution of the differential equation $y_2'=ky_2$. So we can write the above formula equivalently as follows: $$k \in \mathbb{Z} \Leftrightarrow \exists y_1 \exists y_2 \left ( y_1'=y_1 \land y_2'=ky_2 \land y_1 -1 \mid y_2-1 \land k'=0 \right )$$ @JoelDavidHamkins

Comment: I believe that your idea has merit, except that I think you should mean $\mathbb{N}$ rather than $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Should it be $\mathbb{N}$ because of the fact that the divisibility in this ring is defined as the divisibility in the polynomials where the powers are natural and not integers? @JoelDavidHamkins

Comment: I don't think it works with integers, since for example, I don't think $e^x-1$ divides $e^{-2x}-1$ in your ring. I'd be happy if an algebraist confirmed that $e^x-1$ divides $e^{kx}-1$ in your ring just in case $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Is it right?

Comment: Could you take a look at my question : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568636/elimination-of-quantifiers ? Are you familiar with this definition? @JoelDavidHamkins